# Finding Vaccine Appointments in MA

Tags: web-access, webservices, web, webdriver, websession

Everyday I spend a crazy amount of time clicking though each maze of hyperlinks and forms on this horrendous site: https://vaxfinder.mass.gov/

Is there anyway that Mathematica can help speed up the process of finding out if there are available appointments for people with 2+ co-morbidities?

Comment: Perhaps you could describe how you go through the site manually, so that we can help you codify? At present your question doesn't have quite enough detail (for me, a non-US citizen) to help you easily.

Answer (score 5):

> Disclaimer: This answer and all of the codes created only for educational purposes and the author does not hold any responsibility.

> **WARNING:** Since running the codes below will put heavy pressure on site and may prevent others who are really in need of the vaccine from accessing the site, **PLEASE DO NOT RUN IT REGULARLY.**

Base on what I see, you check all the places for availability. Mathematica has different ways to extract data from the web, this solution uses `StartWebSession` which introduced in version 12. basically, it will open a new browser, in this case, **`Firefox`** but you can change it to `Chrome` (step 3) and browse the pages automatically and will create a dataset of all the places:

1- Defined a function to grab links of individual pages:

```
grabLinks[session_WebSessionObject, url_ : Null] := Module[{},
  If[url != Null, WebExecute[session, "OpenPage" -> url];];
  WebExecute[session, "JavascriptExecute" -> "temp00=[];
document.querySelectorAll('a.btn.secondary').forEach(function(elem,i){
  temp00.push(elem.href);
});return temp00;"]]
```

2- Another function to extract table from each page:

```
extractInformation[session_WebSessionObject, url_String] := 
 Module[{name, response, t1},
  WebExecute[session, "OpenPage" -> url];
  name = First@WebExecute[session, "ElementText" -> "Tag" -> "h1"];
  response = 
   WebExecute[session, 
    "JavascriptExecute" -> 
     "if(document.querySelectorAll('div.table-empty').length==1){
  return 'Empty';
}else{return document.querySelector('table').innerText;}"];
  If[response == "Empty", 
   t1 = {<|"Date" -> "-", "Hours" -> "-", "Available" -> "-"|>};,
   t1 = SemanticImportString[response, {"Date", "Text", "Integer"}, 
      "NamedRows"];];
  Return[Prepend[#, "Name" -> name] & /@ t1]]
```

3- Start a session and open the url:

```
mainSession = StartWebSession["Firefox"];

WebExecute[mainSession, "OpenPage" -> "https://vaxfinder.mass.gov"];
```

4- Extract the number of pages and populate page links base on that:

```
numberOfPages = 
  StringCases[First@WebExecute[mainSession, "ElementText" -> "CSSSelector" -> "p.current"], 
     DigitCharacter ..] // Last // ToExpression;

pages = Table["https://vaxfinder.mass.gov/?page=" <> ToString@i, {i, 2, numberOfPages}];
```

5- Extract individual links (places) from pages:

```
links = Flatten[{grabLinks[mainSession], grabLinks[mainSession, #] & /@ pages}];
```

6- apply `extractInformation` on all the links and show the results:

```
result = extractInformation[mainSession, #] & /@ links;

Dataset @ Flatten @ result
```

7- exit the browser:

```
DeleteObject[mainSession];
```

As I explained in the WARNING, I didn't run it in full capacity, here are two sample outputs:

[image]

[image]

If you want to check a particular pages, just slice `pages` before step 5 (starts from page 2 to total pages):

```
(* only pages 1, 2 ,3 *)
pages = pages[[2;;3]];

(* only pages 2,3 *)
pages = pages[[2;;3]];
links = links[[26;;]]; (* do it after step 5 *)
```

The output is a dataset, so you can easily filter those places which have availability:

```
Dataset[Flatten@result][Select[#Available > 0 &]]
```

Full code:

```
grabLinks[session_WebSessionObject, url_ : Null] := Module[{},
  If[url != Null, WebExecute[session, "OpenPage" -> url];];
  WebExecute[session, "JavascriptExecute" -> "temp00=[];
document.querySelectorAll('a.btn.secondary').forEach(function(elem,i){
  temp00.push(elem.href);
});return temp00;"]]

extractInformation[session_WebSessionObject, url_String] := 
 Module[{name, response, t1},
  WebExecute[session, "OpenPage" -> url];
  name = First@WebExecute[session, "ElementText" -> "Tag" -> "h1"];
  response = 
   WebExecute[session, 
    "JavascriptExecute" -> 
     "if(document.querySelectorAll('div.table-empty').length==1){
  return 'Empty';
}else{return document.querySelector('table').innerText;}"];
  If[response == "Empty", 
   t1 = {<|"Date" -> "-", "Hours" -> "-", "Available" -> "-"|>};,
   t1 = SemanticImportString[response, {"Date", "Text", "Integer"}, 
      "NamedRows"];];
  Return[Prepend[#, "Name" -> name] & /@ t1]]


mainSession = StartWebSession["Firefox"];

WebExecute[mainSession, "OpenPage" -> "https://vaxfinder.mass.gov"];

numberOfPages = 
  StringCases[
     First@WebExecute[mainSession, 
       "ElementText" -> "CSSSelector" -> "p.current"], 
     DigitCharacter ..] // Last // ToExpression;

pages = Table["https://vaxfinder.mass.gov/?page=" <> ToString@i, {i, 2, numberOfPages}];

links = Flatten[{grabLinks[mainSession], grabLinks[mainSession, #] & /@ pages}];

result = extractInformation[mainSession, #] & /@ links;

Dataset@Flatten@result

DeleteObject[mainSession];
```